# Why cucumber can't find my test scenarios

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

```
"A:\Testes Ruby\apresentação ifpe
λ cucumber

0 scenarios
0 steps
0m0.000s"
```

Everytime that I try to run the command "Cucumber" this happens. And I can't find what is wrong.
Because I put the step definitions and the env is correct too (I think).

This is the document structure:
[documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt5P8.png)

And this is the step definitions:

```
  Dado('o site da Kabum') do
    pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  end
  
  Quando('fizer o login') do
    pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  end
  
  Quando('escolher todos os produtos necessários') do
    pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  end
  
  Então('ir para o carrinho') do
    pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Forgot to salve the things that I've done. xD